# Provide several download option for same image in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

Would anybody have any idea of how to create several download option of the same image in Durpal 7.

The sample website is: http://www.travesto.com/content/101jpg-anime-animated where several download option is enabled.

I would like to create a similar option for my birthday photos. I think may be views module is used here. BUt not sure. If anybody have any idea of doing this. plz help me....

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean different resolutions? Simply, you have to upload them, and link the files.

Then there are the following modules:

- [DownloadFile](http://drupal.org/project/download_file)
- [Download](http://drupal.org/project/download)

Comment: Yes, I mean several resolution download link of each image. For example, a.jpg is the original image and I would like to provide download option of like 1024X800, 400X200 etc.

Comment: like i said the page u linked realised it simply with a lot of different files, u see it at the link destination

Comment: But there are several links of the same image which provides severarl resolution download option. Below the image, you would see...    
Download different resolution

    1024x1024
    1024x768
    1152x864
    1280x1024
    1280x720
    1280x800
    1280x960
    1366x768
    1400x1050
    1440x900
    1600x1200
    1680x1050
    1920x1080
    1920x1200
    1920x1440
    320x240
    320x480
    480x272
    640x960
    800x600
    852x480

Comment: http://www.travesto.com/imagecachedl/1440x900/travesto-wallpaper-anime-animated-1279944698.jpg, the resolution is in the URL as Parameter, u can implement that with the menu hook look for wildcard

Comment: could you please explain a little detail?

Comment: u have to write an own module, which registers the menu_hook and implement the download yourself. Or you go through the Module like the 2 i linked and check for modules which over the resolution download

Answer (score 0):

You can create a content type like 'gallery' and you can insert a 'image' image field then you create a set of media image preset.
For example 'small-download', 'medium-download', 'big-download'.

Now, in your theme, you overwrite 
field--image--gallery.tpl.php
some code like this:

```
    <div class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
       <?php if (!$label_hidden): ?>
          <div class="field-label"<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $label ?>:&nbsp;</div>
       <?php endif; ?>

      <div class="field-items"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
        <?php foreach ($items as $delta => $item): ?>

          <div class="field-item <?php print $delta % 2 ? 'odd' : 'even'; ?>"<?php print $item_attributes[$delta]; ?>>

              //here you have to find [with print_r($item)] where in the $item  
              //is stored the image url and put it in $url 

              $image = array(
                'style_name' => 'thumb', 
                'path' => $url
                );

              theme_image_style($image);

              l('Download small', image_style_url('small-download', $url));
              l('Download medium', image_style_url('medium-download', $url));
              l('Download big', image_style_url('big-download', $url));
          </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: is this possible to do this using tokens? or other way? for example, if i use panels and is it possible to add customize code like the code?

Comment: This is a field override. 
If you print this field [in node or in a block views or in a panel pane..] this field will be displayed in this way: image + 3 link